# Deleting rows without CASCADE DELETE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database in SQL Server, where I have one table for customers, and each customer can have multiple bookings, but a booking can belong only to one customer. The point is that I have written an API and then a client side app using WPF, but I just noticed that I cannot delete a customer without actually previously deleting the associated bookings with that customer. My T-SQL looks like this roughly:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FullName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [Id] ASC
))

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Booking](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](10,2) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerId] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [Id] ASC
))

ALTER TABLE [dbo].Booking WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_Customer] FOREIGN KEY([CustomerId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Booking] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_Customer]
GO
```

Then, I have a delete stored procedure defined like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteCustomer
    @Id int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[Customer]
    WHERE Id = @Id
END
GO
```

But as I said I cannot delete a customer that has existing bookings. One way is surely to use CASCADE DELETE, but I don't want also the bookings to be deleted if the customer is deleted. Any idea how to overcome the problem or any workarounds?

Comment: Get rid of the foreign key or only _mark_ the customer as deleted via some custom flag (this will also allow you to undelete it if needed).

Comment: @Marvin Is it possible to somehow get rid of the foreign key, do the deletion and then return the foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options I see are:

1. Make the foreign key column `[CustomerId]` nullable, and then use `on delete set null`
2. Use a soft delete on the `Customer` table, e.g. a bit column such as `IsActive` or `IsDeleted`.
3. Disable the foreign key: `alter table [dbo].Booking nocheck constraint [FK_Booking_Customer]`
4. Drop the foreign key.

In most situations I would implement the soft delete option.

Comment: Thanks for the options. The first one works fine in my scenario.